# Precompiling assets using Rails and Docker fails: Webpacker and Node.js version issue. How can I upgrade the node version in my docker container?

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, docker, heroku, docker-compose

I'm building a fairly simple Rails application (Rails 5.2 and Ruby 2.5.1) using Docker to manage my development environment and to deploy to Heroku. My app works well locally, but fails upon deploy to Heroku. The issue seems to be that the assets files (more specifically webpacker) isn't loading correctly.

I think the solution is to precompile assets locally and then push to Heroku. However, when I try to precompile assets I get the following error:

```
Webpacker requires Node.js >= 8.16.0 and you are using 8.9.3
# Please upgrade Node.js https://nodejs.org/en/download/
```

So it seems like an easy fix: just update Node.js as the error message suggests. However, I'm having a difficult time getting the update to persist in my Docker container.

This is what my `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM ruby:2.5.1-alpine

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.0.2

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
      binutils-gold \
      build-base \
      curl \
      file \
      g++ \
      gcc \
      git \
      less \
      libstdc++ \
      libffi-dev \
      libc-dev \
      linux-headers \
      libxml2-dev \
      libxslt-dev \
      libgcrypt-dev \
      make \
      netcat-openbsd \
      nodejs \
      openssl \
      pkgconfig \
      postgresql-dev \
      python \
      tzdata \
      yarn

RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.2

WORKDIR /web

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
RUN bundle check || bundle install

ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV RACK_ENV production

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --check-files

COPY . ./

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

I thought that running `apk add` with the `--update` flag, would ensure I had the latest package versions, but that does not seem to be the case.

Here is my `docker-entrypoint.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rails s -b '0.0.0.0'
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - database
      - redis
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development

  database:
    image: postgres:12.1
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.7

  sidekiq:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - web
      - database
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
    entrypoint: ./entrypoints/sidekiq-entrypoint.sh

volumes:
  gem_cache:
  db_data:
  node_modules:
```

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "stimulus": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.1"
  }
}
```

I've tried so many different approaches to upgrading node in my Dockerfile at this point, but nothing seems to work.

Every time I add a new line to the `Dockerfile` to try to install or upgrade node, this is how I test it:

1. rebuild the docker container: `docker build .`
2. run the container: `docker-compose up`
3. sh into the shell: `docker-compose exec web sh`
4. try to precompile assets: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

In addition to trying new install commands in my Dockerfile, I've also tried to directly update the node version in the shell. But no matter what I do when I run `node -v` in the shell, it returns `v8.9.3`.

As you can imagine it takes a long time to rebuild the docker container every time I make a one line installation change so I've probably spent 2x as long just trying to solve this config issue than I have actually building my app. It's been extremely frustrating so any help on this front would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution here wound up being somewhat simple. The Alpine version I was using `ruby:2.5.1-alpine` was pretty old and didn't support a node version greater than `8.9.3`.

I updated to `ruby:2.5.2-alpine3.9` and that seemed to fix the issue.